# matplotlib.widget not working in ipython notebook

Tags: matplotlib, widget, jupyter-notebook

I have been copy pasting code snippets from http://goo.gl/J802b0 into an ipython notebook console to try out these matplotlib features.  I get the sliders and buttons appearing after I shift-enter the code cells, but without any functionality.

I am running ipython notebook --pylab inline.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Here is an example that plots a sine wave and adds next and previous buttons
that supposedly will change the axes, but I get no interactivity:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
line, = plt.plot(t, np.sin(t), lw=2)

class Index:
    dt = 0
    def next(self, event):
        self.dt -= 1
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(t + self.dt))
        fig.canvas.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        self.dt += 1
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(t + self.dt))
        fig.canvas.draw()

callback = Index()
axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])

bnext = Button(axnext, '>')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)

bprev = Button(axprev, '<')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)
```

Answer (score 4):

The figures are served in the web-browser as a png and do not have kind of image map (look at the source of what the note book serves to you) so I don't think this functionality exists in in-line figures yet.

The code should work if you use one of included interactive backends (with your gui toolkit of choice).